# Multiple Pointer Declaration With typedef

Tags: c++, pointers, typedef

In C++, if we want to declare multiple pointers, we would do something like this: `int *a, *b, *c;` where we would have to put an asterisk `*` in front of each of them. if i write this code: `typedef int* ptr; ptr a,b,c;`? Will they all be pointers, or just a?

Comment: Any reason you couldn't use `std::unique_ptr` and then just typedef that?

Comment: @Mgetz The reason being this is the first i time i have heard of unique_ptr.. Sorry, i am still i noob in C++. Thank you i will check that later.

Comment: Any reason why you have to define more than one variable on the line.  It makes the code more difficult to read.  (As does this sort of typedef.)

Comment: @Mgetz Any reason why he should?  He's got pointers to `int`.  There's practically never any reason to dynamically allocate `int`, so presumably, they don't point to dynamically allocated memory.

Comment: @JamesKanze I think that the other way round wastes many lines, and actually makes the code more difficult to read. This way instead, everything seems more organized in case of a long code.

Comment: @JamesKanze I'm think he's just using `int` as a placeholder, my comment was more directed towards avoiding using raw pointers if it can be avoided.

Comment: @Mgetz Not everyone wants/is able to use C++11 features. @ OP Here's a page with more details on smart pointers : http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory

Comment: This is a perfectly good question about basic C++ syntax, which is completely unrelated to the pros and cons of different memory management methods.

Comment: @user2653125 I'm not sure what you mean by "long code"; a function should rarely be more than about 10 lines.  And it's a lot cleaner and easier to understand if each line does one, and only one thing.

Comment: @Mgetz Which is exactly the problem.  Most pointers in a well written C++ program will be raw pointers, because they're used for navigation.  There are a few cases where `std::unique_ptr` is valid locally, but they certainly don't dominate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, typedef isn't just a matter of text substitution (like a macro would be).

```
typedef int* ptr;
```

introduces a new name, "ptr", for the type `int*`.

If you write

```
ptr a, b, c;
```

all of a, b, and c will have the same type, `int*`.

Note that

```
const ptr p;
```

likewise isn't the same as

```
const int* p;
```

Since `ptr` is a pointer type, the `const` applies to the pointer; the equivalent is

```
int* const p;
```

Comment: that's one reason to using typedef instead of Macro.

Answer (score 3):

Hmmm, interesting... Lets see. Say I don't know many things about typedefs, what do I do?

---

**Answer:** I test it by myself. Below there is a code which answers your question:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef int* pointer_t;
pointer_t a1, b1, c1;
int* a2, b2, c2;

int main() {
  a1 = new int; // ok
  b1 = new int; // ok
  c1 = new int; // ok
  a2 = new int; // ok
  b2 = new int; // compile-time error
  c2 = new int; // compile-time error

  delete a1; // ok
  delete b1; // ok
  delete c1; // ok
  delete a2; // ok
  delete b2; // compile-time error
  delete c2; // compile-time error

  return 0;
}
```

---

**Conclusion:** Both a1, b1, and c1 will be pointers, but only a2 will be a pointer.

Comment: For b2 and c2 to be pointers, you'll need to declare them `int *a2, *b2, *c2`. As said by others, `pointer_t` will be of type `int*`, so a1, b1 and c1 will be `int *`. Splitting your declarations one in each line you have: `pointer_t a1; pointer_t b1; pointer_t c1; int* a2; int b2, int c2;`

Comment: Thank you Captain Obvious. but by asking it in stackoverflow i learn more than just understanding how it works, but also why, and some other suggestions like the answers above. Still i agree, you made a good point. :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they will be pointers:

```
typedef int* pointer_to_int;

int main()
{
    int a , b , c;
    pointer_to_int ptr_a , ptr_b , ptr_c;

    ptr_a = &a;
    ptr_b = &b;
    ptr_c = &c;

    *ptr_a = 1;
    *ptr_b = 2;
    *ptr_c = 3;

    std::cout << a << " " << b << " " << c;
}
```

The output is:

> 1 2 3

Thats because `typedef` defines [**type aliases**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typedef). On the other hand, if you could use C++11, I recommend you to use [`using aliases`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias) instead of `typedef`, because its syntax is much clear:

```
using ptr_to_int = int*;
```

and also works with template aliases:

```
template<typename T>
using vector_t = std::vector<T>;
```

Answer (score 0):

They will all be a pointers, the `typedef` is `int*`.

Comment: History will forget this u-turn :-)